# Как сделать Вызов в CMD некоего экзэшника с параметрами запуска в C# исключая write read bat файла

Tags: c#, cmd, bat

Здесь (С#) происходит создание батника и вызов сторонней `file.exe` в *cmd* с некими параметрами.

Есть ли возможность миновать создание и запуск через батник?

```
string[] batnik = new string[3];        
string str = "any value";
batnik[0] = "cd ...\";
batnik[1] = "file.exe <command line> " + str + $" -p {textBox1.Text}";
batnik[2] = "pause";
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"...\file.bat", batnik);

string parameters2 = String.Format("/k \"{0}\"", @"...\file.bat");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", parameters2);
```

Comment: А в чём, собственно, проблема?

Comment: А зачем вам тут консоль? Что мешает просто запустить сразу программу с нужными аргументами? Как запускать вы уже вон знаете `Process.Start`, пишите там путь к `file.exe`, аргументы, запускайте и читайте вывод также через `Process` (если программа его должна писать).

Comment: `ProcessStartInfo` помогло

Answer (score 0):

не разобрался  для чего здесь `UseShellExecute = false`? пишет что по умолчанию для .NET Core apps false должно быть, вот нашел такое решение:
наверное можно закрывать тему.

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("...//file.exe", string arg);
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        Process procCommand = Process.Start(startInfo);
        string line = procCommand.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        procCommand.Close();
        textBox1.Text= line;
```